# Is there a way to hash user ID for use in URI (path)?

Tags: python, django, security

Is there a way in Python (Django specifically) to build a URL for a file that uses a hashed user ID?

I want to use the hashed ID for file authentication, i.e compare `request.user.id to` the section of the file path.

I’ve researched Django’s “make_password” but it seems like overkill for my need. I’ve read about `os.urandom` but it doesn’t sound like it can be reversed.

In the end my goal is to protect user IDs from being a part of URLs, but allow for easy file access authentication/permissions.

Comment: can u give us an example?

Comment: What about md5?

Comment: I think you need something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/uuid.html).

Comment: Davi: example would be turning ID like “09876543” these are stored in a char field because of leading zeros into something like “ae5wj47bte”. Guven: how does one use md5 in that case?

Comment: Guven I guess I could use UUID, but I want a shorter version. Would I just need to truncate it, or can I generate a specific length? Also, are UUIDs url safe?

Comment: Also, I really would like to be able to salt the hash so that I can reliably reverse the hash if need be.

Comment: @CamParker, salting hashes doesn't make them reversible.

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci, I think the idea is to make the hashes hard to generate. MD5 is trivially simple; anybody can guess that an ID might be 1, 2, or 3, for example, and generate hashes from those inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [Hashids](https://hashids.org/python/) which, despite the name, aren't cryptographic hashes since they're reversible:

> Hashids is a [small open-source library](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python) that generates short, unique, non-sequential ids from numbers.
>
> It converts numbers like 347 into strings like “yr8”, or array of numbers like [27, 986] into “3kTMd”.
>
> You can also decode those ids back. This is useful in bundling several parameters into one or simply using them as short UIDs.

[A library exists](https://pypi.org/project/django-hashid-field/) to add Hashids fields to Django's ORM.

Comment: For this specific use-case, Sqids (formerly Hashids) is not recommended. From the Sqid homepage itself: "Not Good For: User IDs: Can reveal user count if anyone finds out the encoding alphabet"